# Haskell VS Code lexical error at character '\DC4'

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, character, lexical

Whenever I try to use code evaluation in VS Code / VSCodium, I get this exact message:

```
lexical error at character '\DC4'
```

even in fresh projects. Other features work fine so far. How do I fix that?

Comment: DC4 is the ASCII character of rank 20 (decimal), perfectly standard conformant but not supposed to be there. Maybe some component of VS Code expects text input to be UTF-8, and it is not, or conversely. It might hurt for example if you happen to have, say Cyrillic characters in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because my projects' folder was lying inside a folder with a cyrilic name. Relocating projects so the absolute path is in 100% latin characters have solved the problem.